# ggplot2: geom_text labels in different positions based on condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data like:

```
somedata <- data.frame("x" = 1:3, "7"= 1:3, 
                       "Label" = c("green","blue", "na"), 
                       "Bold" = c('snake', 'na', 'dog'))
```

I want to produce a graph with labels using these conditions:

1. If `Label` has a value, that is directly under the data point.
2. If there is no value in `Label`, but there is in Bold, then that value is directly under the data point.
3. If there are values in both Label and Bold, the Label value should go directly under the data point, and the Bold value should be directly under the Label value.

Values from the bold column should be in bold fontface.

Here's what I have so far:

```
ggplot(somedata, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Label), size=3, vjust=1.7, hjust=0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Bold), size=3, vjust=1.7, hjust=0.5, fontface = 'bold')
```

This works fine as long as there aren't values for both Label and Bold. For the `green snake` point, they overlap. How can I get them to read `green` directly under the data point, and `snake` directly below `green`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add a negative sign for one `vjust` (and I corrected your dataframe) :

```
library(tidyverse)
somedata <- data.frame("x" = 1:3, "y"= 1:3, 
                       "Label" = c("green","blue", NA), 
                       "Bold" = c('snake', NA, 'dog'))
ggplot(somedata, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Label), size=3, vjust=-1.7, hjust=0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Bold), size=3, vjust=1.7, hjust=0.5, fontface = 'bold')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have two rows of labels at most, the following hack using plotmath expressions would work:

```
somedata$actual.label <- paste0(
  "atop(",
  ifelse(somedata$Label == "na", "", as.character(somedata$Label)),
  ",",
  ifelse(somedata$Bold == "na", "",
         paste0("bold(", as.character(somedata$Bold), ")")),
  ")")

somedata$actual.label <- gsub("atop(,", "atop(",
                              somedata$actual.label,
                              fixed = TRUE)

> somedata
  x y Label  Bold            actual.label
1 1 1 green snake atop(green,bold(snake))
2 2 2  blue    na             atop(blue,)
3 3 3    na   dog         atop(bold(dog))
```

[image: plot]

```
ggplot(somedata, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = actual.label),
            vjust = 1.5, parse = TRUE) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.5, 3)) # allow some space for the label's 2nd row
```